# ' numbers.sort().reverse() '... Why these codes don't work well attached together?

Tags: python

I got a list like this

```
numbers = [1 ,4,2,6,7,3]
```

I want to arrange this list in descending order.

```
numbers.sort().reverse()
print(numbers)
```

This is what I tried. But it doesn't work, just showing error message.

```
number.sort()
number.reverse()
print(numbers)
```

This works well, but it seems too long.

What's wrong with the first one? And Why can't I attach two functions in case of `numbers.sort().reverse()`? Why do some codes works well attached together, while some other don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the functions return.  `list.sort` returns `None` because it modifies the list in place instead of returning a new list.  You can pass `reverse=True` to `sort` to accomplish what you want without the extra function.  You could do the same with the `sorted` function which does produce a new list:

```
l = [1, 2, 1]
print(sorted(l, reverse=True)) # [2, 1, 1]
print(l) # [1, 2, 1]
l.sort(reverse=True)
print(l) # [2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python `sort()` has a built in parameter `reverse`:

```
numbers.sort(reverse=True)
```

It also doesn't *return* a value; rather it just manipulates the list it was called upon, so `.reverse()` after that will not see a value to reverse.

Answer (score 1):

That's because sort doesn't return a list, and therefore you cannot apply a sort to a `None type`

You are sorting `inplace`, e.g, changing the elements order of your array on the *same instance*

You don't receive a sorted copy of your array when doing sort, basically

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 7]
print(list_.sort()) # None
```

To do everything on the same line, you can do something like:

```
sorted(list_, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because sort just sorts the current list but does not return anything.

Use something like `new = sorted(l)[::-1]`